# Is it necessary to compile Dart for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I noticed something by accident.  When I create a simple AngularDart application, it runs just fine in Chrome and Firefox (not just Dartium).  I understood that this would take an extra step to compile but LO! it runs, as is, in Firefox and Chrome.  What gives?

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

void main() {
  applicationFactory().run();
}
```

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>


</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello {{name}}!</h3>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">

  <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Chrome running Dart]

[image: Firefox running Dart]

Comment: What exactly do you think "packages/browser/dart.js" does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DartEditor runs `pub serve` in the background which serves files to the browser.
When a browser can't process Dart a JavaScript routine is executed which requests the JavaScript source and `pub serve` transpiles (compiles) on the fly to JavaScript and serves this generated JavaScript to the browser.

So, yes, you need to compile to browsers which don't have native Dart support.

`pub build` (when run from the CLI runs in release mode by default) in addition to generating JavaScript from Dart also does tree-shaking to remove unused code and minification to make the result JavaScript smaller.
`pub serve` doesn't do this.